# Neo4j vs OrientDB object mapping options vs Tinkerpop Frames

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, orientdb

We are starting a new social startup and from what I learned so far graph database is the way to go, I am currently trying to figure out which one to use.
I started comparing OrientDB and Neo4j, we are writing in Java and object-graph mapping is important for us.

I started with Tinkerpop Frames (for easy migration in the future) but it seems that there is only one way mapping (maybe I am missing something) from the graph to an object, also the mapping is only with interfaces (it's more like defining a schema with interfaces rather than having your application objects mapped to the graph - again maybe I'm missing something :/ ).

Because I can't use Tinkerpop I need to choose one specific DB (migration will be harder :/ ), I saw that OrientDB uses reflection and neo4j has jo4neo which uses annotations, I am currently leaning towards jo4neo because it is more familiar and without reflection seems faster (I havn't tested this yet)

I would love hearing any input on this, maybe I missed something with Frames, really any input would help

Comment: Hi, the OrientDB's Object implementation uses proxies. Where did you see the usage of reflection?

Comment: Hey Luca, here http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/ObjectDatabase at the Introduction, have I misunderstood ?

Comment: The reflection is only used to discover the classes at the startup, but then all is managed by Java Proxies ;-)

Comment: Ok, but if I create a class using "new" (not a proxied one) and then try to map it, it will be mapped using reflection right ?

Comment: In that case yes. So use OObjectDatabaseTx.newInstance(Class). The returned object is proxied.

Comment: hmm, yea but I am writing n-tier so the class is not created at the DAL, this means that higher layers need to "know" the lower DB implementation (or creating a wrapper which feels less natural). I will probably use neo4j with Spring Data until Spring Data implmentation will be available for orientDB (saw that it was in progress), thanks for the help!

Comment: You could create object via factories in a DDD approach. The factory could have a OrientDB impl that call that method. You would have maintain the code decoupled by OrientDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use jo4neo, that project is pretty outdated. I would go with http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j for annotation driven OGM.

Answer (score 1):

[datanucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/) JDO implementation supports both Neo4j and OrientDB

Comment: only through a 3rd party plugin which supports only DataNucleus 2.X ;-(